# HTML Text around float under float - Chrome bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-float

The following code in Chrome results in the text overlapping with the top of the second `div`. In FF it looks OK. Is it really a bug, or I just fail to understand some basics ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
    <div style="float:right; width:100px; height:45px; background-color:gray;">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:right; float:right; width:200px; height:45px; background-color:blue;" >
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm I think it is a bug :/ I tried to mess around for a bit, and the only solution I got is this (note, the text doesn't wrap around the gray div, no idea why...) this might help:
http://jsfiddle.net/RxAUx/56/

Comment: Of course for every particular case it's possible to find some workaround, like your wrapping floated divs with another div, or adding some thick margin so that text will overlap with the margin only. Yet I have that _feeling_ :) that I didn't grasp some basic idea and it's not really a bug.